# Generate HTML file with Spring that execute AngularJS scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I have an HTML page that displays information on a given country. I would like now to generate this HTML with Java, so that then I can reuse the code for another HTML page and don't duplicate it.

I created this GET mapping in my controller

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/region/{regionId:[\\d]+}",  produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String regionPage(@PathVariable int regionId) {
        return pageService.getRegionPage(regionId);
    }
```

And the `pageService.getRegionPage` returns for example the following String (that I formatted)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bhutan</title>
    <script src="/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/regionController.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="mainPage" ng-controller="regionController as controller" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-include="'/html/regionContent.html'"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I my browser, the javascript files are correctly downloaded. I also see that the title of the tab is "Bhutan". However the AngularJS does not execute and the page is blank.

How can I fix this?
Thanks a lot

NB: If I create an HTML file containing this same HTML code, and serve it as

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/region/{regionId:[\\d]+}")
    public String regionPage(@PathVariable int regionId) {
        return "/region.html";
    }
```

it works perfectly well

Comment: "so that then I can reuse the code for another HTML page and don't duplicate it." -> does it mean that you "insert" the html code described there into another html page, as a sub element of another page ? And you call this path: /region/{regionId:[\\d]+} with some javascript code ?

Comment: No, but if I want to have
`@RequestMapping(path = "/city/{cityId:[\\d]+}",  produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String cityPage(@PathVariable int cityId) {
        return pageService.getCityPage(cityId);
    }`

then `pageService.getCityPage` and `pageService.getRegionPage` would share almost the same code, except for the angularjs controller.

Comment: Personnaly, I would compare the content of the response with the two scenarios inside the browser dev console. Do I get some errors or warning in one scenario ? Are headers the same etc